# Replace apostrophe in unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I'm trying to replace an apostrophe in a python unicode string. In the debugger it looks the following:

```
u'Tu veux aller trop vite! Pour répondre à cette question, tu dois d\\'abord trouver le bon code.'
```

After the replacement it should have `\'` instead of `\\'`. 
When I try to replace the apostrophe, nothing happens. What should I do?

The following shows plus/minus the code:

```
def convert(sheet, file):
    from xlrd import open_workbook
    from lxml import etree
    value = sheet.cell(1, 1).value
    #value = u'Tu veux aller trop vite! Pour répondre à cette question, tu dois d\\'abord trouver le bon code.'
    child = etree.Element('string', name=key.encode('utf-8'))
    child.text = value
    file.write(etree.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: did you try string.__repr__()

Comment: how does it relate to string literal you posted?

Comment: could you show the output of `print(repr(value))`. The value in your code is not valid Python

Answer (score 1):

Your literal is invalid, you escaped backslash, but doing so failed to escape single quote (`'`), thus terminating literal too early. Try those, depending what are you going to achieve:

```
print u'Tu veux aller trop vite! Pour répondre à cette question, tu dois d\\\'abord trouver le bon code.'

print u"Tu veux aller trop vite! Pour répondre à cette question, tu dois d\\'abord trouver le bon code."

print u'Tu veux aller trop vite! Pour répondre à cette question, tu dois d\'abord trouver le bon code.'

print u"Tu veux aller trop vite! Pour répondre à cette question, tu dois d'abord trouver le bon code."
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you to achieve here. Do you want to replace the '\\' by '\' in a string variable of your python script? As your literal is invalid, I have done a small change.

Here's an idea to replace your '\\' by '\' using a regexp

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import re
    str= u"Tu veux aller trop vite! Pour répondre à cette question, du dois d\\'abord trouver le bon code."
    str2=re.sub(r'\\', "", str)
    print str
    print str2
```

Output:

```
Tu veux aller trop vite! Pour répondre à cette question, du dois d\'abord trouver le bon code.
Tu veux aller trop vite! Pour répondre à cette question, du dois d'abord trouver le bon code.
```